# Transitive reduction not provably minimal

Tags: graph-theory

I was under the impression that when constructing a [*transitive reduction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) (which, unlike a *minimum equivalent graph*, allows for new edges to be added), you can simply replace any SCC with a simple Hamiltonian cycle.

This excerpt from The Algorithm Design Manual has me confused however:

> "A linear-time, quick-and-dirty transitive reduction algorithm
> identifies the strongly connected components of G, replaces each by a
> simple directed cycle, and adds these edges to those bridging the
> different components. Although this reduction is not provably minimal,
> it is likely to be pretty close on typical graphs."

Can anyone explain when this would not be minimal? How is it ever possible to construct a smaller equivalent component than a simple directed cycle?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed replace every strongly connected component with a cycle when computing a transitive reduction. But that's not *all* you have to do! The proposed algorithm won't reliably deliver a minimal result because it does nothing to eliminate redundant edges *between* connected components.

The simplest illustration of this is this acyclic graph with three nodes:

[image: Graph with edges from 0 to 1, 0 to 2, and 1 to 2]

The algorithm in the question simply returns this graph as-is, with no edges removed. This is not minimal; the edge from 0 to 2 is redundant and can be removed.

To guarantee that you really reach a transitive reduction (i.e. a graph with the *minimum* number of edges), you would want a two-step algorithm along these lines:

1. identify connected components and reduce them to simple directed cycles (i.e. run the algorithm in the question)
2. treat each of these components/cycles as if it were a single node, such that the edges *between* connected components form a DAG. Run some other algorithm specifically for computing the *transitive reduction of a DAG* on this.

Since the algorithm proposed in the question simply skips the second step outright, it usually won't return a minimal graph.